# Data for north symbol

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to use the north symbol and scalebar in the `ggsn` package. My query is that if I have more than 1 maps in the `geom_polygon` incantation where I have that one map is a subregion of the second map, can I use anyone of them in the call to north or scalebar ? I don't think it matters because they are both maps of the same region.

Here is a reproducible example. Can I use `north(tidy(m1))` or `north(tidy(m2))` ? I don't think it matters. Similar query I have for scalebar as well.

```
library(tigris)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

m1 <- states()
m2 <- counties()

head(m1@data)

head(m2@data)

library(ggmap)
library(ggsn) 
library(broom)


ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = m2 ,aes(x= long,y = lat, group = group),col = "grey",fill = NA ) + 
  geom_polygon(data = m1 ,aes(x= long,y = lat, group = group),col = "brown",fill = NA )  + 
  north(tidy(m2))
```

Comment: does it look different? Also try `north2`

Comment: It does not look different to me. Since I am not an expert on this, I would like to hear an expert's opinion.